# Derivative Greater Than 0 Implies Surrounding Derivatives Not Equal To 0

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f: \textrm{dom}(f) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$

Assume $f'(x_0) > 0.$

i.e. $~ \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} > 0$

i.e. $~\exists l > 0 \textrm{ s.t. } \forall \varepsilon_1 > 0, \exists \delta_1 > 0 \textrm{ s.t. } \forall h \in \mathbb{R}, 0 < |h| < \delta_1 \Rightarrow \Bigg| \displaystyle\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} - l \Bigg| < \varepsilon_1$

I would like to prove that $\exists a, b \in \mathbb{R} \textrm{ s.t. } a < x_0 < b \wedge \big( \forall x \in (a, b), f'(x) \neq 0 \big).$

I did something similar here, except I proved $f(x) \neq f(x_0)$:
[Proof Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EulGfXIkkr9Rmfd62wgC0t-KZoDoauZ5/view?usp=sharing)

This time, it seems more complicated. There may be a counterexample, in which case I shouldn't try to prove this.

Help needed.

Comment: The counterexample to your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778059/derivative-greater-than-0-implies-one-to-one-function-in-neighborhood) is already a counterexample to this question.  That function's derivative has zeroes in every open interval containing $x_0$.

Comment: Your statement is generally true if $f'$ is continuous at $x_0$. But then it just becomes a general statement about continuous functions: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0$, and $f(x_0)\neq y$, then there is an interval $(a,b)$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(x)\neq y$, for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ but not continuously differentiable, then it is wrong in general. Try $$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,x\mapsto\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac x2,&x\neq 0\\ 0,&x=0\end{cases}.$$

Then $f$ is differentiable everywhere, $f'(0)=\frac12$, but $f'$ is $0$ in every neighbourhood of $0$.

If $f$ is continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, then it is true by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Without any further assumption on $f$ your statement is wrong. Indeed it might be that $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$ only. For instance consider $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as
$$g(x) = \cases{0\quad\mathrm{ if }\;x\in\mathbb{Q}\\1 \quad\mathrm{ otherwise}}\,.$$
Now let $f$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x) = x + (x-x_0)^2g(x)\,.$$
$f$ is differentiable only in $x_0$ where the derivative is $1$.

Comment: What if "f '(x) not equal to 0" included "f ' undefined at x"? Can you find a counterexample where f '(x) = 0 nearby?

Answer (score 1):

I understand where this intuition comes from, but it actually is not true. Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+ax & : & x\neq 0 \\
0 & : & x=0
\end{array}\right.$$

where $0<a<1$. This function is continuous on the whole domain and is differentiable everywhere. The derivative satisfies

$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+a & : & x\neq 0 \\
a & : & x=0
\end{array}\right.$$

Thus, $f'(0)>0$, but if we consider what happens as $x\to 0$, the function is dominated by the term $-\cos(1/x)+a$, which must equal $0$ an infinite number of times. Thus we can't find any interval containing zero where the derivative is nonzero.